# How to use or should I use case_when to change values when using the list of variables

Tags: r, list, selection, case-when

I believe what Id like to do is relatively simple, I just don't seem to know the proper terminology to get the answer to my question. I have a data frame with 9 variables. I want to create a new variable that is based on variables from another column. Simple example:

```
my.df <- data.frame(col1 = sample(c(1,2), 10, replace = TRUE),
        col2 = as.factor(sample(10)), col3 = letters[1:10],
        col4 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace = TRUE))


    col1 col2 col3  col4
1     2    8    a  TRUE
2     1    3    b FALSE
3     2    4    c FALSE
4     2    2    d  TRUE
5     2    7    e FALSE
6     2    9    f  TRUE
7     2   10    g FALSE
8     2    6    h FALSE
9     1    1    i FALSE
10    2    5    j FALSE
```

I would like to create col5 by using information from col3. I am expecting something like this:

```
my.df<-my.df %>%
  mutate(col5 = case_when(col3 = c("a", "b", "c") ~"green",
                          col3 = c("g", "h", "i", "j")~"red",
                          col3 = c("d", "e", "f")~"purple"))
```

I am expecting results like this:

```
 col1 col2 col3  col4    col5
1     2    8    a  TRUE  green
2     1    3    b FALSE  green
3     2    4    c FALSE  green
4     2    2    d  TRUE  purple
5     2    7    e FALSE  purple
6     2    9    f  TRUE  purple
7     2   10    g FALSE  red
8     2    6    h FALSE  red
9     1    1    i FALSE  red
10    2    5    j FALSE  red
```

Error is must be a logical vector, not a character vector.
If I change (col3 == c("")... using the == I get warning messages and problem that longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.

My solution eventually was to create a vector of just the names and then use %in%.  However, I really think there should be a simple way to do this?  OR maybe using different commands where I don't have to change values row by row.

Example of what I did get to work, which I had to do for each color:

```
grn<-c("a", "b", "c")
my.df<-my.df %>%
      mutate(col5 = case_when(col3 %in% grn~"green")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%in%` to compare multiple values -

```
library(dplyr)

my.df %>%
  mutate(col5 = case_when(col3 %in% c("a", "b", "c") ~"green",
                          col3 %in% c("g", "h", "i", "j")~"red",
                          col3 %in% c("d", "e", "f")~"purple"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
my.df %>%
    group_by(grp = cumsum(col4)) %>%
    mutate(col5 = setNames(c('green', 'red', 'purple'), 
       c('abc', 'ghij', 'def'))[str_c(col3, collapse='')]) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
    col1  col2 col3  col4  col5  
   <int> <int> <chr> <lgl> <chr> 
 1     2     8 a     TRUE  green 
 2     1     3 b     FALSE green 
 3     2     4 c     FALSE green 
 4     2     2 d     TRUE  purple
 5     2     7 e     FALSE purple
 6     2     9 f     FALSE purple
 7     2    10 g     TRUE  red   
 8     2     6 h     FALSE red   
 9     1     1 i     FALSE red   
10     2     5 j     FALSE red
```

#### data

```
my.df <- structure(list(col1 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L
), col2 = c(8L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 1L, 5L), col3 = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), col4 = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```